# Changes month with day in ParseExact Method

Tags: c#

In this method of my program I'm taking two dates from the user(called `fromDate` and `toDate`), later in another method, program finds the sales in a shopping mall and some other properties related with sales between these two days.

However, when the user enters 11/05/2014 for example, I don't know why but program changes it to 05/11/2014. Here is my method :

```
static Tuple<DateTime, DateTime> PromptForDateInterval()
{
    CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

    Console.WriteLine("From Date : (dd/MM/yyyy)");
    DateTime fromDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Console.ReadLine(), "dd/MM/yyyy", provider);

    Console.WriteLine("To Date   : (dd/MM/yyyy)");
    DateTime toDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Console.ReadLine(), "dd/MM/yyyy", provider);

    Console.WriteLine(fromDate.ToString());

    return Tuple.Create<DateTime, DateTime>(fromDate, toDate);
}
```

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You mean "changes" it when displaying it to the user in `Console.WriteLine(fromDate.ToString())`? That is it displaying in the format of your computer's regional settings

Comment: Really. Thanks @Rhumborl. Now I changed it. Then my error is not related with this one, thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
DateTime fromDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Console.ReadLine(), "dd/MM/yyyy", provider);
```

and

```
DateTime toDate = DateTime.ParseExact(Console.ReadLine(), "dd/MM/yyyy", provider);
```

you create a two datetime objects that will be initialized with what the parser will return using the specified format and provider.

When you write the datetime object to console using `.ToString()` method.

```
Console.WriteLine(fromDate.ToString());
```

u're implicitly using the region of your machine, but you will have the datetime objects well defined into tuple.

And if you're looking at `Day, Month, Year` properties of your datetime objects you'll get what you need.

Later edit: If you need to create a tuple that will have only the string representation of your dates you will need a `Tuple<string, string>` and to add to that Tuple `fromDate.ToString(format)` and `toDate.ToString(format)`

For list of formats here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx, but you can create custom formats too.

I won't return a `Tuple<string, string>` instead of a `Tuple<Datetime, Datetime>` because if you're looking at returned object (`Tuple<string, string>`), you won't know the format.

Comment: Then, Am I need to create Tuple with shorter versions of DateTime Objects

Comment: I cant use string cause my data's format is Date. I mean at least I will Format this string to the DateTime

Answer (score 0):

The format you used to parse the date is not stored in your `DateTime` variable. To output it in the same format you parsed it, just use the same format again:

```
fromDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

So don't worry, the data stored in `DateTime` is correct, you just used it "wrong" in `Console.WriteLine`.